# innerHTML returns blank?

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg, innerhtml

This a wordy problem, so I'll try and be as specific as possible.

I have two wysiwyg text editors held within two separate containers. In a function run on onclick of an `<a>` tag, one container is slid up and inserted before the other container. This causes the wysiwyg box to completely break, so I remove it and then reinitialize it. The problem I'm having is getting the content within it.

This is the HTML structure of wysiwyg:

```
    <div class="rightFieldContainer">
        <div class="wysiwyg" style="...">
             <ul class="panel" role="menu">...</ul>
             <div style="clear: both;">...</div>
             <iframe frameborder="0" style="..." tabindex="0">
                 <html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                     <head>...</head>
                     <body style="..." class="wysiwyg">
                        <b _moz_dirty="">WHAT I'M TRYING TO GET</b></strike><br>
                     </body>
                 </html>
             <iframe>
          ... (all remaining tags are closed)
```

The path to the content is my function is specified as such:

```
     var content = $("#someContainer1").find(".rightFieldContainer").children(" .wysiwyg").children()[2].contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
```

Using innerHTML returns a blank and html returns undefined. What's more curious is that if I use the same/similar path to get the content of another textbox that is never meant to be moved, it works fine.

I understand that it's impossible to hope for a clear answer since the problem itself is a little vague, but just an alternative to innerHTML or reasons why it might not work are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content in an iframe is not navigable using selectors from the parent document. To get the document for the iframe you need to do:

```
$("#someContainer1").find(".rightFieldContainer").children("iframe").contents();
```

`.contents()` gets the document for the iframe so you can then find things within it from the parent page, assuming that the contents of the iframe are on the same domain.

```
var content = $("#someContainer1").find(".rightFieldContainer").children("iframe").contents().find(".wysiwyg").html();
```

To simplify this you should give your iframe a class/id and select it directly as such:

```
var content = $("#someContainer1").find("#youriframe").contents().find(".wysiwyg").html();
```

Comment: Thanks, using contents() proved to be a better path to the body. That still didn't fix it completely but I realized the problem was actually something I was passing into the functions. Nevertheless, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a different selector to ensure you're pulling the body of the iframe?

```
var content = $("#someContainer1").find(".rightFieldContainer > div.wyiswyg > iframe body.wysiwyg").html();
```